# Using data from one controller action to another without making database call

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-controller, grails-services

I am using grails 2.4.4

I have below details.

```
projectController
def index(){

    def projectList = REST WEB SERVICE CALL TO GET LIST OF PROJECT FROM DB.
}

def search1(){  // AJAX CALL

    def projectList = REST WEB SERVICE CALL TO GET LIST OF PROJECT FROM DB.
    def resultList = SEARCHING PROJECTNAME FROM ABOVE projectList.
}

def search2(){ // AJAX CALL

    def resultList = SEARCH BY PROJECTNAME FROM EXISTING projectList WITHOUT MAKING CALL FROM DB.
}
```

I know controllers are stateless.

Even thought projectList remains constant i have to make call to DB?

Is there any way to search from existing projectList without Reloading it from DB.

I am looking for JSF View scope like functionality in grails.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not create a service that loads the list from the database when the service starts then expose a method in the service to return the results when called from a controller? You could also just move the loading of the list into a service and use any number of cache plugins for grails and cache the results. There are any number of ways to do this.

Comment: i am using grails service, the above code is just for Eg. 
And thanks for suggestion on Cache plugin of grails. I will look into cache plugins and let you know.

Comment: "Even thought projectList remains constant i have to make call to DB?" -- if your app is calling a web service to get this information, how does your app know the list has not changed? If you do, then cache as suggested by Joshua Moore.